# Unable to identify a semi-cursive? Kanji

Tags: kanji, handwriting

A friend and I are studying and she showed me this book she couldn't tell what the kanji was after ヒト. We were able to decipher two out of 3 kanji 関わる and 見る (unless we're wrong do correct us).

However, we're unable to find the third one after ヒト.

Also, where can I find an online resource that helps you identify cursive Kanji?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried (1) searching "handwritten kanji recognition", (2) uploading a picture that would be in focus?

Comment: I can't find a site that lets you upload a picture even after searching with those terms

Comment: It seems to be 居. I'm not sure enough to make it an answer, though.

Comment: `we're unable to find the third one...` ← ん？ You're reading from left to right, starting with 「人が関わらなければ」?? 右から（「どれほど奇天烈、奇々怪々なデキゴトも...」から）読んでます？

Comment: I wasn't trying to read it from left to right, I was just describing it from a numerical position point of view. But yes, from a reading perspective I meant the first kanji after ヒトが

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is [視]{み}なければ (from 視る, not 見る), and the third one is 居なければ (from 居る).  Note that 視る is a widely recognized reading of [みる](https://chigai-allguide.com/%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%A6%B3%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%A6%96%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%BA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E7%9C%8B%E3%82%8B/) (but perhaps not an official reading).

Comment: do you have a source for the third one?

Comment: Just my eyes...

Comment: Here's a page with various forms of 居 https://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E5%B1%85/page.html

Comment: @Leebo That is an amazing resource!!! I was looking for something like that! Thank you so much! How did you find this page?

Comment: I googled "居 楷書 行書 草書". 楷書 is standard script. 行書 is semi-cursive. 草書 is cursive.

Answer (score 1):

#### Identifying the kanji

Turning things horizontally and adding furigana:

> どれほど奇天烈【きてれつ】
>   　　奇々【きき】怪々【かいかい】なデキゴトも
>    
>   ヒトが居【い】なければ
>   ヒトが視【み】なければ
>   ヒトが関【かか】わらなければ

Remember that vertically written Japanese is read from top to bottom, from right to left -- so the character you were stuck on, 居, is the sixth fully-written kanji from the start of the text (excluding the 々 ditto marks).

Comment: I just meant it was the 3rd kanji on the list of kanji we couldn't find, not from a reading point of view. I'm not that new! haha